# trying to write a food ordering sys for homework in python

Tags: python, dictionary

im learning python and for my homework i wanna make a food ordering program and get the receipt of the products purchased with the prices for the total. im struggling to get the billing process as i cannot get all the products chosen by the user displayed on the receipt

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.now()
name = input("Enter your name: ")
address = input("Enter your address: ")
contact = input("Enter your phone number: ")
print("Hello   " + name)
print("*"*31 + "Welcome, these are the items on on the menu."+"*" * 32 )
print("Menu:\n"
      "1.Burger:150.\n"
      "2.Fried Momo:120.\n"
      "3.coffee:60.\n"
      "4.Pizza:180.\n"
      "5.Fried Rice:150.\n"
      "6.French Fries:90.\n"
      "7.Steamed Dumplings:150.\n"
      "8.Chicken drumsticks:120.\n"
      "9.Chicken Pakoras:120.\n"
      "10.American Chop Suey:200.\n")
prices = {"1.Burger":150,
          "2.Fried Momo":120,
          "3.coffee":60,
          "4.Pizza":180,
          "5.Fried Rice":150,
          "6.French Fries":90,
          "7.Steamed dumplings":150,
          "8.Chicken drumsticks":120,
          "9.Chicken Pakoras":120,
          "10.American Chop Suey":200
}

continue_order = 1
total_cost, total = 0, 0

cart = []
while continue_order != 0:
    option = int(input("Which item would you like to purchase?: "))
    cart.append(option)
    if option >= 10:
        print('we do not serve that here')
        break

    elif option == 1:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 150
        print("The price is: ₹" + str(total))
    elif option == 2:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 120
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 3:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 60
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 4:
        qquantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 180
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 5:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 150
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 6:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 90
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 7:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 150
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 8:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 120
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 9:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 120
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 10:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 200
        print("The price is: " + str(total))

    total_cost += total

    continue_order = int(input("Would you like another item? enter Yes--> (1) or--> No (0):"))

print('='*30)
print('='*30)
print("Your receipt:\n")
print("Date: " + str(x))
print("Name: " + name.title())
print("Adress: " + address)
print("Contact number: " + contact)
for option in cart:
    print ("Item: %s. Price: %s") % (option, prices[option])
print("Quantity: ",quantity)
print("Total Price: ", total_cost)
print('='*30)
print("Thank you for shopping here, have a great day ")
print('='*30)
```

but i get an error line 95, in 
print ("Item: %s. Price: %s") % (option, prices[option])
KeyError: 1

any solution or better ways to improve the code would be really great

Answer (score 2):

Try using [F-Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). They let you format text far more easily. Here's an example.

```py
x = "hello!"
print(f"shr4pnel says {x}")
>>> shr4pnel says hello!
```

The problem in this case is that option == 1. 1 isn't a key in the dictionary so nothing is output. Hope this helps. This is because the dictionary does not have 1 as a key. To access the item the dictionary would have to be formatted like this.

```py
prices = {1: "burger", 2: "hot dog"}
print(prices[1])
>>> burger
```

Comment: You use a defferent dctionary than in the original question. The problem is with the indexing, not with the output.